# Linux timer_settime() generating segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, timer

I'm using the posix timer functions for a project with an example from [timer_create() man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create).

The code, basically the same as the example, starts with establishing the handler for timer signal.

```
    struct sigaction whohas_sa;
    // establish handler
    whohas_sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    whohas_sa.sa_sigaction = whohas_timer_handler;
    sigemptyset(&whohas_sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIG_WHOHAS, &whohas_sa, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigaction whohas");
```

Then I have two functions to create and set the timer.

```
void set_start_timer(timer_t timerid, int freq_secs)
{
    // set and start the timer
    struct itimerspec its;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = freq_secs;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = freq_secs;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
    {
        DPRINTF(4, "settimer failed! \n");
        errExit("timer_settime");
    }

    DPRINTF(4, "leave set timer\n");
}

void create_timer(int SIGNAL, timer_t timerid)
{
    DPRINTF(4, "create timer\n");
    sigset_t mask;

    // block timer signal temporarily
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGNAL);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigprocmask");

    // create the timer
    struct sigevent sev;
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
        errExit("timer_create");

    printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);
}
```

When I call these two functions, creating timer succeed but set&start gives a Segmentation fault.

```
    whohas_timerid = NULL;
    create_timer(SIG_WHOHAS, whohas_timerid);
    set_start_timer(whohas_timerid, 3);
```

whohas_timerid is a global variable.

```
    timer_t whohas_timerid;
```

The output is as below:

```
    create timer
    timer ID is 0x877e918
    set timer
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The code is running on a Ubuntu 16.04 i386.

Could anyone help me find out the problem, or is it not the problem with these timer codes? Thanks!

Comment: Does the segfault actually occur in `set_start_timer`, or could it possibly be in the signal handler?

Comment: there's a print of "set timer" but no "leave set timer" so I believe it's a segfault in calling timer_settime(). @NateEldredge

Comment: You’re passing ``whoas_timerid`` as a pointer. Writing to it has no effect outside the function, you’re only writing to a register so ``timer_settime`` is being passed NULL. If you want to use it as an out variable, it has to be a pointer-pointer ``timer_t *`` in ``create_timer`` in order to overwrite the global. Or set ``whoas_timerid`` directly from there without passing it as an argument. Or even better, return it from the function.

Comment: Thanks! I returned the timer_t from `create_timer` and write it to `whohas_timerid`, timer_settime seems work great now. @PhilippGesang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Philipp Gesang: You’re passing `whoas_timerid` as a pointer. Writing to it has no effect outside the function, you’re only writing to a register so `timer_settime` is being passed `NULL`.
>
> If you want to use it as an out variable, it has to be a pointer-pointer `timer_t *` in `create_timer` in order to overwrite the global. Or set `whoas_timerid` directly from there without passing it as an argument. Or even better, return it from the function.

Philipp solved my problem! I returned the `timer_t` from `create_timer` and write it to `whohas_timerid`, `timer_settime` seems work great now.